# How to use DataInputStream to read binary data from a file and print to the console?

Tags: java

This was the question asked: Write a program to read planet details from binary.txt using DataInputStream and print planet details on the standard output.

However, the program below throws an IOException. I can't figure out the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;

public class LA4ex2b  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream input=null;
        try
        {
            input= new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/user/workspace/LA4ex2a/binary.txt"));
            String str;
            // read until the string read is null i.e. read till end of file
            while ((str = input.readUTF()) != null) {
                String token[] = str.split(" "); // tokenizes the string with
                                                    // space as a delimeter

                for (int i = 0; i <token.length; i++)
                {
                    if (IsDouble.IsaDouble(token[i]))



System.out.print(Double.parseDouble(token[i]));
                    else
                        System.out.print(token[i]);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            if (input!= null)
                input.close();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the binary file:   MercuryA‹ €   @³      DÑxU~€D?  VenusA™Ì     @Ç£ÌÌÌÌÍE  4 XQ  EarthA¡Õn    @Èê&ffffE Â{ '/¶  MarsA«,-@   @ºŠ     Dàÿ¦ ¬qÑ  JupitorAÇ2/È   A t@    E˜Ž’™‹cÏ  SaturnAÕLºp   @ým€    E}]jÛ-jô  UranusAåcú–   @èõÀ    EQô½îÖ×  NeptuneAðÇY`   @è/€    EU0•u*«ý  PlutoAö ’x   @¡Ä     D…ƒ¿=Ä!(

Comment: It would be better to post the file in the _question_ and not in a comment. (or u could upload the real file and provide a link to it)

Comment: This is indeed a binary file; but don't you know the format of it?

Comment: Can you provide your stack trace?

Comment: This is a textual representation of a binary file only, it's not exact at all. You can't post the content of a binary file in text form unless you go "1110011101...".

Comment: And what is IsDouble.IsaDouble that you have used.

Comment: Doesn't give an option to upload.

Comment: //IsDouble class with the method to check if a string is an double or not
public class IsDouble {
 public static  boolean IsaDouble (String s)
 {
  try
  {
   Double.parseDouble(s);// converts the string into a double
   return true;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   return false;
  }
 }

}

Comment: I dont know what's a stack trace, but when i debug it, i understand that there's a problem reading it from the file, the minute it reads, it throws an exception.

Comment: Upload your txt file to dropbox and share the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dcqgucbaot4xaa/binary.txt

Answer (score 2):

if you're reading a binary file, you cannot assume it´s stored as text.

instead, you must know beforehand what are each field data type and read them like

```
    DataInputStream input= new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("xyz")));
    double d = input.readDouble();
    int i = input.readInt();
    char c = input.readChar();
```

Comment: for that I will need if statements, however, for an if statement i need to read first and store in a variable and then check. The problem here is that i dont know which type of variable to use to store in.

Comment: you need to find the description of what is stored in the binary file, otherwise, you'll end up trying to reverse engineer the file by trial and error

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there is "Mercury" - planet name - but no text representation of a double "1.23", so it is really binary data. Maybe [input.readDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readDouble%28%29)? Always do an internet search for the javadoc.